# Why do we use absolute value here in this limit?

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sqrt{4-4x+x^2}}{x-2}$$

Then I calculate the limit

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{4-4x+x^2}{(x-2)^2}$$

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(x-2)(x-2)}{(x-2)(x-2)}=1$$

I thought I could just cancel the factors and just write that the answer is 1.
But my book says that the answer should be this:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\mid(x-2)\mid}{(x-2)}=1$$

I know that the fraction above does not have a limit when x approaches 2. But where does the absolute sign come from? Why could we cancel one of the (x-1) in numerator, but not the other? I really appreciate some help!

Comment: $\sqrt{(x-2)^2}=|x-2|$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sqrt{4-4x+x^2}}{x-2}
=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sqrt{(x-2)^2}}{x-2}
=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{|x-2|}{x-2}=-1$$

Comment: Ohh, so when i take the square root of something that is squared, then I always must use the absolute sign?

Comment: @Mathomat55 - That is correct, because it has to remain positive

Comment: By convention and for definiteness, $\sqrt{x}$ (for non-negative real $x$) always means the non-negative square root.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate it! :)